# Mongoose updateMany :: wont find any on given condition

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have updateMany function as follows

```
Article.updateMany({author: userId}, {author: anonym}, function(err, updated) {
    if (err) {
      res.send(err);
    } else {
     res.send(updated);
    }    
});
```

userId is = 6068b57dbe4eef0b579120c7

anonym is = 6069870676d6320f39e7e5a2

for testing purposes I have a single article in MongoDB as follows

```
db.articles.find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("6068b591be4eef0b579120c8"), "favoritesCount" : 1, "comments" : [ ], "tagList" : [ ], "title" : "Martin", "description" : "Testib", "body" : "Asju", "author" : ObjectId("6068b57dbe4eef0b579120c7"), "slug" : "martin-2hzx78", "createdAt" : ISODate("2021-04-03T18:36:01.977Z"), "updatedAt" : ISODate("2021-04-03T18:53:29.809Z"), "__v" : 0 }
```

You can see that article has "author" : id field in it which currently shows userId as author.
I want to update that field and transfer authorship to anonym user.

When I send this request to postman I get following response

```
{
    "n": 0,
    "nModified": 0,
    "ok": 1
}
```

And database remains unchanged. What am I doing wrong here ?

Comment: have you tried converting userId string type to objectid type in query part `{ author: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(userId) }`

Comment: @turivishal I tried it now, still does not work.
I did it so
 Article.updateMany({author: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(userId)}, {author: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(anonym)}, function(err, updated) {
    if (err) {
      res.send(err);
    } else {
     res.send(updated);
    }    

  });

Comment: You should check other possibilities, 1) make sure database connection with right database 2) make sure collection name is correct one sometime it `articles` or `article` 3) check with `find()` query are you getting records or not. 4) try to use `$set` operator in update part

Comment: @turivishal there is also something weird going on, this is what backend log shows going on during this request

Mongoose: articles.updateMany({ author: ObjectId("6069f818cd72a90a7a45a969") }, { '$setOnInsert': { createdAt: new Date("Sun, 04 Apr 2021 17:32:08 GMT") }, '$set': { updatedAt: new Date("Sun, 04 Apr 2021 17:32:08 GMT"), author: ObjectId("6069f818cd72a90a7a45a96a") }}, {})

i console log userId inside function, its
6068b57dbe4eef0b579120c7
but backlog is showing different ?!?!
the filter userId is definitely not correct one, i dont know where its getting it.

Comment: you are missing something, try to close node server and reconnect it and try again.

Comment: @turivishal ok ill try. I also tested so, I commented out this function and put in there Article.find({}, function(err, docs) {
      res.send(docs);
    });
and it finds correct article, there is only one article created.

Comment: @turivishal restart did not help. Something is definitely wrong whit the function filter and set userId and anonum values are.

I console.log, inside function, console.log(mongoose.Types.ObjectId(userId));
and it backlog gives it value of 6068b57dbe4eef0b579120c7 which is correct. But also backlog shows that when this call is initiated
{ author: ObjectId("6069ff148331980a787157eb") 
these numbers are supposed be same, its the same variable, i do not change it. There does not exists any other articles or users inside database, that number in filter is coming out of nowhere

Comment: @turivishal also, there are no other databases or collections

Comment: @turivishal I found my problem. Before update I was doing queries for userId and anonym, and it was a classic case of race condition. Those variables were not ready yet. I made those previous queries with await and it works perfect.

Comment: this is the learning part for you, don't focus only one point, try to debug everything step by step. second thing is to post all information in your question, otherwise it is hard to predict this kind of problems by others :).